# Schema.org type for news article?

Tags: schema.org

What is the correct Schema.org type for a news article post?

Is it [`Blog`](https://schema.org/Blog)?

Or is there something better to denote that it is a news story that has just happened, not a regular blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best type for that type of content is: **http://schema.org/NewsArticle**.

It is currently used by popular news platforms like [NY Times](http://nytimes.com) and [Daily Mail](http://dailymail.co.uk) in their stories (and you can see how they implemented it in their sites)

Answer (score 0):

There actually are [Articles](https://schema.org/Article) on schema.org.

They also have more specific types like:

- [NewsArticle](https://schema.org/NewsArticle)
- [SocialMediaPosting](https://schema.org/SocialMediaPosting)
- [TechArticle](https://schema.org/TechArticle)

I think [NewsArticle](https://schema.org/NewsArticle) should fit best for something that just happened.